# Mode of a Mixed Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

$X$ has the following mixed distribution:

$P[0] = 0.2$
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
  \frac{0.5xe^{\frac{-x}{100}}}{100} & x > 0 \\
  0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array} \right.$$

Calculate the mode of $X$ .

I think the answer should be $0$ as the maximum value for the $f(x)$ occurs at the point $x=100$ . Here, $f(100) = 0.18 (approx.) < 0.2$ , i.e less than the value which occurs at $0$.

However, the answer is $100$ only.

[MODE of mixed distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147973/mode-of-mixed-distribution) The same kind of question has been answered here but there is no clear cut solution witch which I can agree. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that many of the references define "mode" in terms of a discrete distribution or a continuous distribution.  This is a mixture, so what to do?

Comment: What  is the source of your question?

Comment: This question came in one exam of mine.

Comment: @mjw mode is the value that maximizes the distribution so here max value occurs at 0, that's what I thought but I am not sure.

Comment: Well, that would be a (weighted) delta function at $x=0$, right?  $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{0^-}^\epsilon f(x) \, dx = 0.2.$

Comment: I didn't understand this.

Comment: The delta function is explained here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html